# How to map a F# enum style discriminated union to postgres with npgsql

Tags: postgresql, f#, npgsql

I have a table in PG with field that need to store between 1 to 5. In the F# side I have this enum:

```
type PriceTier =
    | P1
    | P2
    | P3
    | P4
    | P5
```

I'm using directly npgsql, without type providers or ORM. When I send the command with parameters:

```
    let build (row:CustomerRecord) =
        [P("@code", row.code);.... P("@defaultPrice", row.defaultPrice);....]
```

I get the error:

> The CLR type Models+PriceTier isn't supported by Npgsql or your
>   PostgreSQL. If you wish to map it to a PostgreSQL composite type you
>   need to register it before usage, please refer to the documentation.

So I read http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html and do:

```
NpgsqlConnection.MapEnumGlobally<PriceTier>();
```

But this not work because the type is not a true enum, but a F# type.

So, I have 2 questions here:

- Is possible to use the F# type as-is without converting to a enum?
- Is possible to map between the PriceTier -> Int without do the conversion manually?

Comment: Can you make the PG table also with an ENUM field? Is Pg getting the F# name of the ENUM ie., P1, or is it getting a numeric representation?

Comment: Your type definition is not an enum, it us a discriminated union

Comment: @Evan Carroll is using a numeric representation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an F# expert, but if I understand correctly your PriceTier is a discriminated union rather than an enum. Discriminated unions can contain arbitrary fields, so they really don't correspond to enums in any way. If your specific union type is really an enum logically, it may make sense to actually define it as an enum type rather than as a union (see [this post](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/enum-types/) for example), in which case you can use the regular Npgsql enum mapping feature.

Note that I'm not sure Npgsql can even know that your type is a discriminated union - at the end of the day it seems to be just a CLR type just like any other (I may be wrong about that though).